# Calling Async task in a loop?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to call an Async task in a loop and execute it a few times in parallel.

I have a List of items which I split out into smaller lists with 10 items in each list.
Then for every small List I execute the Async task using THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Problem is, its not working.  I'm thinking its because I use the same list each time when it is passed to the AsyncTask - and I think it may be passed as reference.

Do I need to somehow create new Lists dynamically?

```
   //split the ListItems into 10s
        if (actualThumbs.size() > 10){

        List<List<ListItem>> parts = chopped(actualThumbs, 10); // this splits it into parts of 10
        List< ListItem > listToSend  = new ArrayList<ListItem>(); //this is the list to pass
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++){ //for every part


        for(int x = 0; x < parts.get(i).size(); x++){ //for everything in that part
            //add to its own List
            listToSend.add(parts.get(i).get(x));

        }
        //this is the async task
        loadActualThumbs thumbs = new loadActualThumbs();
        //execute multiple threads
        thumbs.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,listToSend );
        listToSend.clear(); //clearing the list ready for a new one - PROBLEM?
     }
    }
    else
    {
        //else just execute AsyncTask normally, this works OK
        loadActualThumbs thumbs = new loadActualThumbs();
        thumbs.execute(actualThumbs);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I tried changing my code, to instead add every List that I want to send to the Async task to another List, and then loop through that List of Lists and send each one:

```
 if (actualThumbs.size() > 10){

                List<List<ListItem>> parts = chopped(actualThumbs, 10);
                List< ListItem > listToSend  = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
                List<List<ListItem>> sendMe = new ArrayList<List<ListItem>>();
            for(int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++){ //for every part


                for(int x = 0; x < parts.get(i).size(); x++){ //for everything in that part
                    //add to its own ListItem?
                    listToSend.add(parts.get(i).get(x));

                }

                sendMe.add(listToSend);// add the List to this List
                listToSend.clear();
             }

                for(int e = 0; e<sendMe.size();e++){ //loop through the list of lists

                    loadActualThumbs thumbs = new loadActualThumbs();
                    //execute multiple threads?
                    thumbs.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,sendMe.get(e) ); // execute async with correct List
                }

            }

            else
            {
                if (actualThumbs.size() > 0){
                //load actual thumbnails
                loadActualThumbs thumbs = new loadActualThumbs();
                thumbs.execute(actualThumbs);
                }

            }
```

Comment: thumbs.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,parts.get(i) );

Comment: very smart! Its amazing how we can over think things.  It seems to be working now, although I'm not sure why it wasn't working in my way above.  Please reply so I can mark as answer!

Comment: Also - since my code separates the BIG List into parts (of 10 each).  If the Big List contains 150 items, then there will be 15 parts, and therefore 15 Async tasks.  Am I right in reading that they will be queued, and only 5 will run at a time?

Comment: I added an answer. Where have you read that only 5 will be run at a time? I also wrote how you can create your own thread pools in case you have doubt about the AsyncTask pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this now :

```
List<List<ListItem>> parts = chopped(actualThumbs, 10);
for(List<ListItem> list : parts) {

    new loadActualThumbs().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, list);

}
```

I am actually not sure what size the threadpool is or if it's a cached thread pool, but you can create your own threadpool with Executors.newCachedThreadPool() and Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int count)... but I'd just go with the AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR....should work :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure where I read that Async Tasks were queued and that only 5 could execute in parallel.  I have noticed that my app is now crashing when there is a lot of items in the BIG list, e.g. 150+.  Is is very wrong to create so many parallel Async Task threads? I mean - why even chop the Big list, why not just start and Aysnc task for each item in the big list and have 150 threads!

Comment: The best thing in my mind would actually be to run everything in one task, one background thread and have the loop in there. Then at the end of the loop call AsyncTask.publishProgress(ListItem...item) and have your newly generated/loaded/whatever ListItem handed over to your UI thread... The question is ... do you really need parallelism!? Or do you just need somthing done in background ... ?

Comment: Without going into two much detail, I am loading thumbails (not from a URL! so I can't use Picasso or Image Loader).  I am loading thumbnails from Dropbox, they generate a URL for you and you have to decodeStream into a file.  It takes 1 -2 seconds to do this for each thumbnail.  If you have 50 thumbails in a folder, it will take over a minute.  So I thought if I execute in Parallel, it will take much less time... does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Ah, there is a little mistake in there... threads don't make anything faster, they just unblock your UI thread, so you perceive responsiveness...and you need the number of cpu cores for your threads...so 150 threads won't bring any advantage :) Imagine it like this... on a singlecore you have either one thread at full power or like 10 with 1/10 power each...

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation.  So is there any point in executing 10+ Async tasks?  It does seem to be loading the thumbnails faster now.  I am trying to work out why it is crashing, and have a look at the logcat.  I'm guessing its an out of memory exception.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Executing 10+ AsyncTasks is fine, the question is again, it is necessary to to have them run in parallel? Rarely... in my opinion :) You have only a limited amount of memory for bitmaps...check out this : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Thanks - ideally I guess I would only like to load the visible items in the List.  So if there was 10 thumbnails needed, then fetch those.  If they scroll then fetch what is visible.  This is beyond my capability since I am a novice to Android and Java

Comment: Just an FYI - its not failing due to the Async Tasks, I think it is failing when I do my initial List load. I load a dummy image (which is a drawable).  If there are 200 drawable Bitmaps added to memory in my bitmap arraylist, its going to crash:                                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            pix.add(image);

Comment: That sounds very probable... If you can't manage, you will want to ask a new question, this is getting out of hand here :) Still I think you will want to read this thoroughly : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute your asynctask for particular interval of time then you may make use of Timer for same ..

Like this ..

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out
                        .println("=================== I am in pooling state ===============");
                GetBookingStatusAsyncTask performBackgroundTask = new GetBookingStatusAsyncTask();
                performBackgroundTask.execute();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

Now when you need to kill this timer ..

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
```

Also make use of boolean check so as to avaoid infinite loop .. i.e if true then execute AsyncTask .. and if false then stop AsyncTask .. just like  ..

```
public void callAsynchronousTask(boolean b) {

        // timer.cancel();
        if (b) {

            System.out.println("============= Check for timer check " + tcheck);
            // execute in every 10000 ms
            tcheck++;

        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("============= Check for timer check + cancelling timer task "
                            + tcheck);

            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
            System.out.println("=============timer is ===" + timer);
            // finish();
            return;
        }

    }
```

When you need to close this task then simply of true / false condition pass like  ..you need to pass this in your AsyncTask.

```
callAsynchronousTask(true); / callAsynchronousTask(false);
```

Hope it helps!..

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps.  I want to execute my Async Task in parallel.  Not on a Timer.